# iOS GestureRecognizer numberOfTouches Returns Wrong Number

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, event-handling, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIScrollView (canvas) that has smaller UIViews (notes) on it. Each of these smaller notes have a pan gesture handler. I have two-finger scroll enabled on my scroll canvas. Two-finger scroll works when both touches are on the canvas, not the notes. But when one or both of the touches are on a smaller UIView (note), the note gesture handler fires instead of the two-finger scroll. I would like the following experience:

If two-touch pan --> scroll.

If single touch pan && touch on a note --> fire noteTouch gesture handler.

**Edit**

Custom UIScrollView hitTest doesn't return the correct amount of touches. Code:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesForView:self];

    if ([touches count] > 1)
        return self;
    UIView *usualView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    return usualView
}
```

Comment: Did you check your hitTest method to see what the returned view for a touch is?

Comment: I have. If a touch falls under a noteview, the hittest returns that noteview (even if I have two touches). I'm trying to return my scrollview if numberOfTouches > 1. But it doesn't return any touches! See edit above.